# Module declare showing error "Index was out of bound of the array"

Tags: f#

I am getting an error in declaration of module of F# project, See below image for the code where error occurred.

[image]

I am trying to build a project but little newbie to F#.

Comment: Modules should contain a simple identifier, not a path with ``.``. Otherwise consider a namespace.

Comment: @Gustavo: But it is not showing such error in other modules e.g. module internal IdfToolbox.Idf.Parser

Comment: That's true. Unfortunately I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I can't repro either. 2 questions: I've seen Intellisense crash and display nonsensical red markers. What if you close and re-open your solution? The other thing is: Even though you see the red squiggly line, does your project compile?

Comment: @Gustavo Top-level modules can happily include a path.  For example `module A.B.C` means module `A` within namespace `B.C`.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/modules).

Comment: @MarkPattison You're right. Apparently it works when it is a top level declaration, but not when is in the ``module x = `` stye. I didn't know it.

Comment: @MarkPattison: I guess you meant to write "`module A.B.C` means module `C` in namespace `A.B` "

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer Ha ha, yes!  Good spot.  I can no longer edit it though.